# Shared Layout + Bootstrap making it impossible to edit table head colors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, colors

So I'm working with someone else's code here, new to Bootstrap and CSS, and  I simply want to change a few elements on the page, but it's difficult because we're working with a shared layout, making it difficult to track down exactly where this color scheme is coming from. I want the table head to be a certain color, and I've marked it in my sytlesheet as so:

```
  thead{
        color:white;
        background-color: #0c98cf !important;
    }
```

When I run it, however, it displays a different color. Reading some of the stuff online directed me to the Inspect Element, and the "Computed" tab, which should show me the absolute final color and where that came from. However, it shows me that it's displaying the color I want, and that it's coming from my stylesheet, even though the actual color being displayed is entirely different.

After pursuing it a bit further, I found that I can comment out this block of code, which is some kind of..bundle(?) that I'm not familiar with:

```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")
```

now this, obviously breaks a lot of stuff but it makes the table the color I want. This may be a dumb question, but essentially I'm just trying to trace down where these colors are being set so that I can edit them without breaking everything else with spacing and everything.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You're probably just applying the style to the wrong element. Check for parent or child elements that contain the color you are seeing, sometimes things are collapsed, or overlapping, etc. and what element you think you are changing can be misleading. Could you add an example on jsfiddle by chance?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with jfiddle. But I did just try it, and plugged in the cshtml and stylesheet, and it gave me the color I wanted (with a bunch of other errors).

Comment: I dunno  if this will help at all. first time with jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=49O9Kp1Drr

Comment: Link isn't working, but you won't get the same effect in jsfiddle unless you apply all bootstrap files (js and styles). Did you try looking through your browser developer tools at the child elements for `thead` and see if maybe they have a background color applied to them?

Comment: Yeah I've been looking through and haven't found anything yet. I've tried searching for the color code, but can't seem to see where it's being set. It looks like I'm successfully changing it, but yeah something's writing over it. Likely a child element, but can't locate it.